# Alternative to deepcopy() in Julia

Tags: julia, deep-copy

I have the following code in Julia:

```
using LightGraphs
using LinearAlgebra
prop=[1 rand() rand() rand() rand(); rand() 1 rand() rand() rand(); rand() rand()  1 rand() rand(); rand() rand() rand() 1 rand(); rand() rand() rand() rand() 1]
prop=Symmetric(prop)
thresh=sort(unique(prop)
g=[SimpleGraph(0) for a in 1:length(thresh)]
for j=1:length(thresh)
    g[j]=Graph(Int.(prop.>=thresh[j])-I)
end
```

I need to create a copy of `g`, say `g2`, on which I need to use the function `add_edge!` but without modifying the original object `g`. I know that `g2=deepcopy(g)` will do perfectly the trick, but if `g` is very large (it's not the case in this simple example), the function `deepcopy()` takes a large amount of time to create the independent copy. I measured it with `@time`. Isn't there an alternative way in Julia to do what I want without taking a large amount of time for just making the copy of `g`? I have to run the code several times and want avoid to consume time just for copying `g`.

Comment: global scope is  quite slow in julia. You should try putting the code into a function to see if that helps.

Comment: hummmm or perhaps creating a loop with `g` inside, making it then a local variable to accelerate the copy process?

Comment: BTW: `prop = Symmetric(rand(5,5)); prop[diagind(prop)] .= 1` is shorter and easier to scale in dimension.

Comment: oh good! excellent point !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want an alternative to `deepcopy`, which is already doing what you want. It's just that heap memory allocation (as done by deepcopy) takes time.
What you can do is make a single copy of `g`, then update that every time you'd need the `deepcopy` function, it might look like this

```
g_copy = deepcopy(g)
add_edge!(g_copy[i], edge)
# ... do stuff
g_copy .= g
```

In that way you'll just change the contents of `g_copy` but never release the memory, so should be faster. I should mention this is untested (as I can't naturally expand your MWE, which doesn't use `deepcopy` or `add_edge!` at all).